# JavaScript Check for HTTP Server on Local Network

Tags: javascript, http, network-programming, port

I am currently working on a device that would connect to a Wi-Fi network and then host an HTTP server on the local network that you can connect to and configure the device. The problem is that the only way to access the device would be through its local IP. I'd like to make a program in JavaScript that would automatically check each device on the local network and determine the local IP of the device hosting the HTTP server and then redirect to it. Is there a way to do this? According to this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/145339) it is possible to detect if a port is open using something like  `<img src="http://192.168.1.1/favicon.ico" onload="alert('Yay')" onerror="alert('No')">`. Is this a good way of achieving this, and how would I apply this to scanning an entire network? Thanks

Comment: You can only do that if you have a known file on each IP on an http server

Comment: @mplungjan But the file would only need to be present on the device that I'm trying to discover, right? Otherwise, is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: If you're looking for an HTTP server, it will always respond to a request if it is open. But, what if there are 12 HTTP servers (or two)? Which one is the correct one?

Comment: @Randy Casburn Is there a good way to identify the correct server? I don't know much about HTTP servers and JavaScript, but I figured this would be a much simpler solution than trying to make a Bluetooth connection or something like that. Also, what's the best way to scan the entire network? Use a for loop and check every possible ip address matching the default gateway?

Comment: Where/how does this device of yours get configured? DHCP? Leased IP address? Will there be proxies involved? On secure enclaves are automated scanner devices like yours automatically banned as a security precaution?  is the environment completely unknown at  the time of this automated discovery? What happens if your HTTP server is never found? There are so many questions that have so many other dependencies. You are asking the wrong question. I think the correct question would be "what is the current best practice for providing network configuration for an automated device with no UI?"

Comment: I'm not sure if I phrased my initial question clearly enough. The device is not a network scanner, it is a mechanical device that runs at a specific time of day, and that time of day can be set through a web server (which will probably be simply a date/time dropdown which will then write to a file or something similar). The purpose of the network scan, which would run client side, would be so that the user could connect to the device more easily. With that said, what _is_ the best practice for achieving something like that? Like I said, I don't know a ton about networking or JavaScript.